# Making the Children Rows in an Outline View be deleted when their parent is

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How would I do this? I think this has something to do with editing the Outline Views Data Source file. The Outline View is currently is being used with Core Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select the children property, you can select a delete rule in its settings. Select 'Cascade' and the children will be deleted when the parent is.